# Where column in <function returns a collection > in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to achieve something like this:

Example:

Table Customers has columns customer_no, name , age.

some_package package has the following types defined in its spec:

```
type cust_type is record (custs Customers.customer_no);
type rec_type is table of cust_type index by binary_integer;
function some_function return rec_type;
```

I am trying to create a view the goes like this:

```
select ....
from customers c, tablex, tabley 
where c.customer_no in some_function() and
... <<other clauses>>
```

- I cannot avoid using some_function() as the logic uses dynamic SQL statements.
- I get invalid data type error when i try to compile the view

Is it possible to achieve this in Oracle sql? I don't want to use another function and loops to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: your question isn't clear .. explain more with some simple query or examples

Comment: Have updated with an example. Kindly check.

Comment: In SQL the function return types are limited.

Comment: The function compiles fine. It gets problematic when used in the view alone.

Answer (score 0):

No, `type rec_type` is declared in a package and can be used in PL/SQL blocks but cannot be used in SQL statements.

If you want to use a type in SQL statements then you will need to declare it using a `CREATE TYPE` statement like this:

```
CREATE TYPE customers_tab IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

or you can use an existing type like `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST`.

Then change the package to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE some_package
AS
  FUNCTION some_function RETURN SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY some_package
AS
  FUNCTION some_function RETURN SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
  AS
    t_customers SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST;
  BEGIN
    SELECT customer_no
    BULK COLLECT INTO   t_customers
    FROM   customers
    WHERE  MOD( customer_no, 3 ) = 0; -- or whatever your query is.

    RETURN t_customers;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Customers c
       INNER JOIN
       TABLE( some_package.some_function() ) t
       ON ( c.customer_no = t.COLUMN_VALUE );
```